# In VS 2003 combined with Crystal Reports XI, I had to reformat a date coming from XML

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

In VS 2003 combined with Crystal Reports XI, I had to reformat a date coming from XML before sending it to CR so the report could break when the year of the date changed.  The code snippet is below

```
nodeDt = node.SelectSingleNode("ToBatchDt");
dt = DateTime.Parse(nodeDt.InnerText);
nodeDt.InnerText = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff");
```

This worked fine until I upgraded to VS2012 plus Crystal Reports 2013. Now, the report breaks when the date changes, not the year.  I have a feeling that the format for changing the input date field to a datetime field is different.  I think this also causing a related error in another report, which has the following function that used to work and now generates an error.

```
Shared NumberVar nWeek := -1;
Shared DateVar dtProc := Date({Detail.ProcDt});  -- input XML field
Shared NumberVar nSuspenseFile := {Detail.SuspFileAmt};
Shared NumberVar nKonnexAdjClearing := {Detail.KnxAdjClearingBal};
```

the error generated is

A date-time is required here. Details: errorKind Error in File temp_dd082f41-3628-4b1d-8782-70c650697de0 5360_8664_{DC989A3F-C349-451F-AAD5-E89D45E05C8D}.rpt: Error in formula fxInitWeek: 'Shared NumberVar nWeek := -1; '

Thank you.